# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable ?smth wrong with pow()?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def nar( value ):
    leng = len(str(value))
    x = 0
    
    for i in range(len(str(value))):
        while i<leng:
            if leng == 1:
                return True
            
            x = x + pow(int(value[i]), leng)
    if x == value:
        return True
    else: return False
```

This is the error:

```
x = x + pow(int(value[i]), leng)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Function is supposed to take a number, for example 145 and do the following: 1^3+4^3+5^3
where the power is basically the length of this number.

Comment: It seems that `value` is an integer value. It makes no sense to use subscript on integers. Perhaps you wanted `int(str(value)[i])`?

Comment: And instead of multiple string conversions, there are other ways to get the individual digits of an integer value, using division and remainder operations. Think back to when you learned about the decimal system in school, and what happens when you multiply and divide by `10`.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out what this code does.  Inside `while i < leng`, you have code that changes neither `i` nor `leng`.  So you have a loop that either never executes, executes once with `leng == `, or is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that

```
x = x + pow(int(value[i]), leng)
# Replace above line with
x = x + pow(int(str(value)[i]), leng)
```

The error is occurring because value is an integer and integers are not subscriptable. Adding the str(value) allows you to access each number by index.

Also, your code is an infinite loop.

This should work according to your description.

```
def nar( value ):
    leng = len(str(value))
    x = 0
    
    for i in range(len(str(value))):
        x = x + pow(int(str(value)[i]), leng)

    # return x
    if x == value:
        return True
    else: return False

print(nar(145))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `value[i]`. You cannot subscript an integer like a string to get its decimal digits.

In order to extract a decimal digits you have to use the modulo and integer division operators. For example, to get the "4" in "145" you do

```
print((value % 100) // 10)
```

In general, to get the i-th digit (counting from the right and starting with zero), you do

```
print((value % (10**(i+1))) // 10**i)
```

This can be put into a loop to get all the digits.

Or maybe you just wanted `int(str(value)[i])` instead to get the i-th element in the string representation of the value. But all these int-to-string conversions look strange.